# Force the usage of usb driver for an specific device

Tags: linux, ubuntu, drivers, usb, wacom

I'm facing a really odd issue with a Wacom STU-530 device on Ubuntu 16.04.

If I connect the tablet in any port it will start as USB 1.1 (really slow) because it loads the driver: **ohci-pci**

```
[  230.708046] usb 4-1: new full-speed USB device number 3 using ohci-pci
[  230.883203] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=056a, idProduct=00a5
[  230.883217] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  230.883226] usb 4-1: Product: STU-530
[  230.883234] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: Wacom Co.,Ltd.
[  230.883242] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: 8LZQ000683
[  230.896179] input: Wacom Co.,Ltd. STU-530 Pen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb4/4-1/4-1:1.0/0003:056A:00A5.0009/input/input20
[  230.896691] wacom 0003:056A:00A5.0009: hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Device [Wacom Co.,Ltd. STU-530] on usb-0000:00:12.0-1/input0
```

But if I instead connect a (really cheap usb hub) and then the tablet into the usb hub, the correct driver **ehci-pci** is configured and the tablet runs at usb 2.0:

```
[  335.120117] usb 1-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[  335.214488] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=056a, idProduct=00a5
[  335.214501] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  335.214511] usb 1-1.1: Product: STU-530
[  335.214519] usb 1-1.1: Manufacturer: Wacom Co.,Ltd.
[  335.214527] usb 1-1.1: SerialNumber: 8LZQ000683
[  335.221870] input: Wacom Co.,Ltd. STU-530 Pen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.2/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0/0003:056A:00A5.000A/input/input23
[  335.222255] wacom 0003:056A:00A5.000A: hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Device [Wacom Co.,Ltd. STU-530] on usb-0000:00:12.2-1.1/input0
```

Is there a way to force the usage of ehci-pci when I connect the tablet? Maybe using udev?

PD: The device runs at 2.0 in other computers without problem.

> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

I'm executing the DemoButtons (Java) from the [Wacom's SDK](https://developer.wacom.com/en-us/will-products#will-sdk-for-devices). It just open a window and let me interact with the tablet.

Cases:

1) If I connect directly the tablet to the "PC" the software won't work, will end with error LIBUSB -99  Error.

2) If I connect the tablet through the cheap USB 2.0 HUB the software will run without problems.

3) The computer has (2/two) USB 3.0 ports, I've repeated the first two tests on them and the tablet only will work if the hub is in the middle.

When connecting the tablet to the 3.0 port the `BUS Class = root_hub with driver xhci_hcd` will handle the device but the driver will be `usbhid / 12M` (so the device is still USB 1.1).

I've already fixed the Wacom's software by changing an internal timeout of [LIBUSB_BULK_TRANSFER](http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/group__syncio.html#gab8ae853ab492c22d707241dc26c8a805) so the software will run correctly no matter if the tablet is connected directly or through the hub.

The thing is, I would need to find a way to understand why the device is running slower in this hardware since from 3000 computers only in ~350 this error appears, all of them are the same model, same version, same vendor, same O.S (like clones).

Maybe is something related to an specific chiptset or low quality usb chipset?

All the info from hwinfo, lsusb, lsusb -t are the same in the computers (compared by vimdiff).

> WHAT I KNOW:

- libusb_bulk_transfer is running slower (for some unknown reason)
- The O.S is handling the device as USB 1.1 when it clearly works as 2.0
- In about 3,000 PC's with same HW/SW this error only will be present in about ~350. (Same bios versions/same O.S and software installed).

Regards.

M.

Comment: Is the USB hub connected to the same USB port which the tablet was connected to? Also, does the USB hub have it's own power supply?

Comment: @bey0nd yes, I've tried the same port of the machine as well other ports with the same result, the usb hub doesn't have it's own power supply, is just an usb cable with 4 usb ports available.

Comment: Is it REALLY slower, or do you indicate that by the loaded driver? Pls see my answer for clarification.

Comment: I have read a conversation on the kernel mailing-list. Same problem. Someone pointed out, that the device will choose the speed, so the kernel can't be the problem. But the other side, just as you, clearified that this device works anywhere else. So it might indeed be some kernel-timeout or whatever. This is way above my experience.

Comment: A wild guess: Try the rear usb ports. The front ones are from the box and might be of some problem.

Comment: Thanks for the effort @WGRM this is a really specific issue, I've managed to do a workaround by fixing the timeout of the Wacom's driver when using LIBUSB_BULK_TRANSFER, but it is still a workaround.

I will keep investigating on this!

Comment: @WGRM I've already tested all the ports, front and rear, USB 2.0 and 3.0, in none of them the tablet would work connected directly, but it will work if the cheap hub is in the middle of any port.

Comment: I will follow your progress. ;)

Comment: Still no answer... I have found, as with everything, that this site is of more use via search engines and already answered questions... Hint: searx

Comment: Thanks @WGRM I wasn't able to solve it by using Linux, I've opted for chaning the libwgssSTU.so timeout of libuusb bulk operations. This workaround is enough for the company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... I've tried many things:

- Running java with extra parameters to see if the application would run correctly
- Tried to update the BIOS of the device (but it is too old and [has no updates](https://www.dell.com/support/article/es-ar/sln304228/getting-support-for-wyse-products-wyse-download-site-decommissioned?lang=en))
- Looked for a way to disable the ohci driver of being taken, achieved it by using udev but the device won't be recognized or would use another driver. (There would be nosense to make the built-in modules of *HCD, the result would be exactly the same)

Finally I gave up and went for the workaround, setting a timeout for the usb bulk operations of libusb on the libwgssSTU.so driver, the Wacom Demo Buttons would fail by setting:

```
EncodingMode.EncodingMode_24bit_Bulk
```

I've passed our foundings (I've worked on this with a co-worker) to the Wacom Developer Support by JIRA and they would add the change to the source code of the **libwgssSTU.so** driver, the new driver works fine but takes 2 to 3 seconds more of delay in this particular hardware.

I wasn't able to find out why the software would run randomly 1/60 or 1/30 or 1/45 on the machine, but at least I found the workaround.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the reason for this behaviour seems to be USB specific. Kernel.org ([here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/usb/ehci.html)) states the following:

> When USB 1.1 devices plug into USB 2.0 hubs, they interact with the
>   EHCI controller through a “Transaction Translator” (TT) in the hub,
>   which turns low or full speed transactions into high speed “split
>   transactions” that don’t waste transfer bandwidth.

Since there is no specific USB 1.0 module (the USB 2.0 will handle USB 1.1 devices), which could be black-listed, this is no option.

The product page states the device as USB 2. ([here](http://signature.wacom.eu/de/produkte/hardware/stu-530/))
Since the device is not USB 3, we cant unload all modules and load the XHCI first, to let it grab the device.

Please try:
    udevadm trigger
And see, if it get recognized correctly.

And don't forget to upvote my effort! :p

Comment: I've added more information about the problem.